# PDF Viewer.JAR library for android is not working on all versions

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-viewer

i have used this library in my android application to view PDF files within the app

https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library

but the pdf is not showing in all android versions ( not showing on android 4.0+ )

it opens as blank pdf with white pages, or a mix  of the PDF's background colors

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/bhavyahmehta/Pdf-Reader---Writer

Use this library it is good  for viewing pdf

Comment: is there any implementation documentation for it ?